# Tensorflow custom loss for multiple outputs model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am working on a image segmentation and classification model which take one 3D image (64x64x64) and return two outputs (3D mask 64x64x64 and one-hot encoded category). Two outputs has been defined like this:

```
seg_final_stage = Conv3D(seg_classes, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding="same", name="Seg_Final")(decoder1)
output_seg = Activation('sigmoid', name = "Seg_Final_Sigmoid")(seg_final_stage)
class_final = Dense(texture_classes, name="Class_Final")(class_dense3)
output_class = Activation('softmax', name = "Class_Final_SoftMax")(class_final)
    
model = Model(input, [output_seg, output_class], name = Config["Model_Name"])
```

There are two different method that I have tried but both failed, it seems like each output will return its own loss instead of just one loss. Following are the loss function I have now.

```
# Custom loss function
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = tf.reshape(y_true, [-1])
    y_pred_f = tf.reshape(y_pred, [-1])
    intersection = tf.reduce_sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    score = (2. * intersection + smooth) / (tf.reduce_sum(y_true_f) + tf.reduce_sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)
    return score

def dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)

def CCE(y_true, y_pred):
    class_loss = CategoricalCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
    return class_loss(y_true, y_pred)

def hybrid(y_true, y_pred):
    mask_weight = 0.8
    class_weight = 0.2
    mask_loss = dice_loss(y_true[0], y_pred[0])
    class_loss = CCE(y_true[1], y_pred[1])
    
    return mask_weight * mask_loss + class_weight * class_loss
```

The first try:

I use single hybrid loss function that try to sum the dice loss and CCE together with weights. However, the model returns 2 losses like output_seg_hybrid and output_class_hybrid. I thought the y_true and y_pred are formed as array so that I can that the first item to calculate dice and the second item for CCE.

```
model.compile(loss=hybrid,
                  optimizer=Nadam(learning_rate=Config["learning_rate"], beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07, name="Nadam"), 
                  metrics=[hybrid])
```

The second try:

I applied 2 losses like below to ensure the output has corresponding loss so it can return 2 loss and sum-up with weights. What I get is actually 4 losses like Seg_Final_Sigmoid_dice_loss, Class_Final_SoftMax_dice_loss, Seg_Final_Sigmoid_CCE and Class_Final_SoftMax_CCE.

```
model.compile(loss={'Seg_Final_Sigmoid':dice_loss, 'Class_Final_SoftMax':CCE},
             optimizer=model.optimizer, metrics=[dice_loss, CCE], loss_weights = [0.8,0.2])
```

What should I do if I just want to sum-up these two losses as one loss?

Comment: Why are you indexing `y_pred` and `y_true` here `mask_loss = dice_loss(y_true[0], y_pred[0])`?

Comment: I thought y_pred and y_true are going to be array form like outputs parameter in the model construction. Just my thought.

Comment: y_pred and y_true are the all batch of which size is (m, H,W, ...). You do not need to index them inside the function. Probably, that is your error.